# What is the difference between slide and a tie in the Roland TB-03?

Tags: synthesizer, synthesis

Roland´s TB-03 (remake of the legendary TB-303) has a slide effect you can add to a note to let the note 'slide'. But there is also a tie you can use to hold one note to the next note.

Here is an example with 3 steps to create context for my question:

When I add a **slide** on the first step, then step 1 holds the note till step 3. When there is a note on step 2 then the note will be ignored:

[image]

When I add a **tie** to the step 2 then the note on step 1 also holds till note 3:
[image]

In my mind, both do the same. Who can tell me what the difference is?‎

The manual is here: https://www.roland.com/global/support/by_product/tb-03/owners_manuals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slide is a smooth change from one note to a different note. A tie is holding the same note for two or more steps.

Comment: Is a slide the same as an Portamento?

Comment: @Simon Basically, yes.